# A question on 'equivariant' splittings of a short exact sequence of $K$-vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $K$ be a field and
$$
\begin{array}{rcccccccl}
0 &\rightarrow & V' & \xrightarrow{a} & V & \xrightarrow{b} & V'' & \rightarrow & 0\\
\end{array}
$$
be a short exact sequence of $K$-vector spaces. Each such sequence splits, i.e. there is a $K$-linear map $b':V''\to V$ such that $b\circ b'=id_{V''}$.

Now suppose that we have given $K$-linear maps $f':V'\to V'$ and $f:V\to V$ and $f'':V''\to V''$ fitting (as the unlabeled vertical maps) into a diagram
$$
\begin{array}{rcccccccl}
0 &\rightarrow & V' & \xrightarrow{a} & V & \xrightarrow{b} & V'' & \rightarrow & 0\\
 & &\downarrow &&\downarrow & &\downarrow &\\
0 &\rightarrow & V' & \xrightarrow{a} & V & \xrightarrow{b} & V'' & \rightarrow & 0.\\
\end{array}
$$

Suppose that both $f'$ and $f''$ are diagonalizable with different eigenvalues, i.e. none of the eigenvalues of $f'$ is an eigenvalue of $f''$ and vice versa. Does one find an 'equivariant splitting' in this case, i.e. a $K$-linear map $b':V''\to V$ such that $b\circ b'=id_{V''}$ and $f\circ b'=b'\circ f''$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pair $(V,f)$ with $V$ a vector space and $f:V\to V$ a linear map is the same thing as a $k[X]$-module with underlying vector space $V$. The map $f$ is diagonalizable iff the module is semisimple, and the eigenvalues are in that case correspond to the simple direct summands that $V$ has.

Using this, your question can be rephrased as:

> if $0\to V'\to V\to V''\to0$ is a short exact sequence of $k[X]$ modules such that $V'$ and $V''$ are semisimple and do not have isomorphic direct summands, does the sequence split?

which in turn is the same as

> if $V'$ and $V''$ are semisimple $k[X]$-modules with no isomorphic simple summands, is $Ext^1(V'',V')=0$?

and since $Ext$ is an additive functor, this is true if the answer to the following simpler question is *yes*:

> if $V'$ and $V''$ are $1$-dimensional $k[X]$-modules and not isomorphic, is $Ext^1(V'',V')=0$?

The answer to this is indeed *yes*, and one can check it by hand. For example, you can translate the problem back to your original formulation, where it becomes:

> if in the situation of your original question $V'$ and $V''$ are $1$-dimensional, does the sequence split equivariantly?

and this is very easy to do directly.

---

A little more work on the homological algebra side will prove thatin fact what you want is true even if $f'$ and $f''$ are not diagonalizable but merely do not have common eigenvalues, provided that $K$ is algebraically closed)

Comment: This is a great answer! Thank you very much. Just to get this right: no finite-dimension is needed for your argument, isn't it?

Comment: @user8463524, if the field of coefficients is algebraically closed, every possibly infinite-dimensional module over $k[X]$ which is simple has dimension $1$, so yes. (This works differently for other algebras; for example, enveloping algebras of Lie algebras usually have maaaany infinite dimensional modules)

Comment: thank you but I wanted to know if no finite-dimension is needed for the first part of your argument, is it? (e.g. is is true/clear that $Ext^1$ works as you propose for $\infty$-dimensional $V$'s?

Comment: Sure. $\hom$ distributes over arbitrary direct sums in both of its arguments (in the first argument, it turn sums to products) so Ext does too.

Comment: I know that $$\operatorname{hom}(\oplus_i A_i, B)\cong \prod_i \operatorname{hom}(A_i, B)$$ as well as $$\operatorname{hom}(A, \prod_i B_i)\cong \prod_i \operatorname{hom}(A, B_i)$$ and for a finite index set, we have $\oplus=\prod$. But why may I take an infinite sum (i.e. an infinite coproduct) out of the second component? Doesn't $A$ have to be compact (i.e. finite dimensional) for this to work? (See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact+object#CompactnessInAdditiveCategories) or am I mistaken? Tank you.

Comment: If $f:A\to\bigoplus_iB_i$ and $A$ is finitely generated, then $f$ factors through a finite 'subsum', and then $\hom(A,\bigoplus_iB_i)=\bigoplus_i\hom(A,B_i)$. Since simples are finitely generated (and the ring is noetherian, so that simples have finitely generated projective resolutions) this does what you want.

Comment: Dear @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez, please let me ask another thing to understand your answer: Do you mean the "simple" direct summands correspond to the whole eigenspace to a fixed eigenvalue $\lambda$, i.e. $$(k[X]/(X-\lambda))^{\text{(multiplicity of $\lambda$)}}$$ or just to $k[X]/(X-\lambda)$? I guess you mean the second alternative, as you want them to be $1$-dimensional $k[X]$, modules. Is this right? Thank you.

Comment: Dear @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez, sorry but I am totally confused now: Why is the condition on the diagonalizability above actually needed? Let $(b'_1,...)$ be a basis of $V'$. Then extend the lineary independent vectors $(a(b'_1),...) \in V$ to a basis $(a(b'_1),...,b''_1,...)$ of $V$. Then $(b(b''_1),...)$ is a basis of $V''$ and a section of $b$ is defined by the map $c$ sending $b(b''_i)$ to $b''_i\in V$. Isn't it now clear that this section is equivariant since $$bfc(b(b''_i))=bf(b''_i)=f''b(b''_i)$$? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Indeed, *simple* means with no submodules, and over $k[X]$ (with $K$ algebraically closed) that is equivalent to being $1$-dimensional.

Comment: I used diagonalizability to reduce everything to the computation of Ext between two non-isomorphic simple modules. As I wrote in the answer itself, it is easy to extend the result to the case of finite dimensional modules with no common eigenvalues (of possibly infinte dimensional modules which are direct sums of finite dimensional ones, if you want). If you also want all infinite dimensional modules, then more care is needed because then there are modules with *no* eigenvalues (like the vector space of Laurent polynomials $k[x^{\pm1}]$, for example)